# Symfony2 doctrine update schema from specific entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If I run

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

It will update my database from all entities.

I need to update database only for the User entity, what is the solution?

One solution is to define a custom entity manager and then pass that entity manager to

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em="custom"
```

But maybe it exists something faster without defining a custom entity manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the command documentation, there is no such option. If this is something you have to do only once, I'd suggest to use the `--dump-sql` option to get the required SQL instructions, and manually run the ones you need.

P.S. I fail to understand what's the reason to only update the schema for an entity, and leave all the rest of entities not sync'd with the database. That sounds like a recipe for getting db errors.

Comment: I currently am in such a situation(and since you are wondering why anyone would want to do this). I have a DB from a very old legacy system that was very badly done. And I am asked to extract certain entities given certain conditions. I find it easier to have doctrine map to part of the entities to do comparisons rather than go messing around queries myself (does that make sense?) So I want to add one entity that will help me compare against data but I do not want to run a mass update on the whole db that can risk deleting information.

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi yes it does make sense. If I understand correctly, you have a Doctrine entity partially mapped with the database because that helps writing your code, but you don't want to automatically sync the entity definition with the table structure because the table has some other / different fields. Then the above solution makes sense.
A totally different way to go would be to use [migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) but that is not exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: yes exactly that is my situation, partially mapped entity. I ended up manually adding the columns and tables and wanted and proceeding from there. Migrations would have worked if I cared to have a repeatable scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually use the Doctrine SchemaTool class to generate an SQL diff based only on a single entity. You’ll need access to Doctrine’s EntityManager – the example below assumes access to Symfony’s container.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(YourEntity::class);
$sqlDiff = $schemaTool->getUpdateSchemaSql([$metadata], true);
```

The variable `$sqlDiff` will now contain an array of SQL statements that are needed to bring the database schema up to date with your entity mapping.

The second argument passed to `SchemaTool::getUpdateSchemaSql()` is important – without it, the default behaviour would be to generate `DROP TABLE` statements for every other table that appears in your database.